# Reshape error while trying to store values in a vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, reshape

I wrote the following interpolation code in Matlab using LaGrange's interpolation method, but when trying to store the values in a vector (L(i) = ....), i keep getting reshape errors (Elements must not change).

I am not sure what to make of that, and i apologize if this has already been asked before, but i have tried searching for this, but people that had this problem were actually trying to use the reshape function.

All i'm trying to do is store the results of the J loop in a vector.

```
syms X
x = [-1, 0, 2]
y = [4, 1, -1]

i = 1
j = 1
P = 0

while i < 4
  L(i) = 1
  while j < 4
    if (i ~= j)
      L(i) = L(i) * (X - x(j)) / (x(i) - x(j))
    end
    j = j + 1
  end
  P = P + y(i) * L(i)
  i = i + 1
end
```

Comment: What does the `end` above the line `P = P + y(i)*L(i)` do? Did you miss some code? and if you remove that `end`, your code executes without any error

Comment: @SardarUsama The first end is for the if statement, the second for the j loop, and the third is for the i loop. I'm curious, what is the result for P? Maybe this isn't working because i'm using Matlab 6.1?

Comment: Where is the `j` loop? There is only one loop in your code which is `while i<4`

Comment: where is the `reshape` function under consideration for that matter? xD

Comment: Oops, i forgot the J loop. Fixed it. Btw, that is what i don't understand. I didn't use the reshape function, and i'm getting errors for it.

Comment: @AlexRD first of all, it sounds like you intend to loop over j again, but you never return it to its original state (i.e. j=1). Why not write this as a for loop? (or better yet, try and vectorise it?)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Oh, wow. Can't believe i forgot that. You're right, also. I re-wrote it with for loops, and it's a lot cleaner. Need to work in my indentation as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting a similar error as you with this code, and was able to fix it be initializing L in advance.  Here is your original code with the modifications here (the `clear all` is just to make sure nothing funny is happening).

```
clear all;
syms X L;
L(1:3) = [1 1 1];
x = [-1, 0, 2]
y = [4, 1, -1]

i = 1
j = 1
P = 0

while i < 4
  while j < 4
    if (i ~= j)
      L(i) = L(i) * (X - x(j)) / (x(i) - x(j))
    end
    j = j + 1
  end
  P = P + y(i) * L(i)
  i = i + 1
end
```

Comment: Yes, this solved it! I'll update the code with for loops as well.

Comment: Great!  I am sure you'll improve the code in a number of ways, and am just glad you could get past that initial error.

Answer (score 1):

You initialized `L` as a double array with this `L(i) = 1` but then you're trying to store symbolic contents in it. You need to initialize `L` as a symbolic array since you want to store the same contents in it. So add this line before your loops:

```
L = sym('L', [3 1]);
```

Also avoid using `i` and `j` as variable names since these are reserved for imaginary numbers.

Comment: I have tried using your method, but i get the following error: 

**Error using ==> sym/sym  Second argument  not recognized.**

Even if i do it like: syms X L it says "**Index exceeds matrix dimensions**". By the way, i have re-written the code using N and K, and with for loops.

Comment: @AlexRD If you exactly used the code that you provided in the question with the line I suggested, you'd not receive any error. I have verified it again

Comment: Maybe it's because i'm using an old version of matlab?

Comment: @AlexRD I believe it has nothing to do with that.  I think you're not using it correctly

Comment: I copy pasted the code in the exact same way it was posted, but still the same error message.

Comment: @AlexRD then may be you're right about the version thing.  I don't know what MATLAB 6.1 used to be